# Getting occupancy bit masks for bitboards

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bit-manipulation, chess

I'm playing with bitboards to represent a chess board and check for legal moves. The thing that I'm stuck with is calculation of occupancy between the source and destination squares in sliding piece attacks. **I don't want to do it by lookup**, so I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to get a mask for the squares in between **without a lookup**. For example, in the following board there is a Rook on c4:

```
8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
4 0 0 R 0 0 0 0 0 
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  a b c d e f g h
```

Given a bitboard that represents empty squares (or occupied squares, whatever is easier) and a pseudo-valid move Rf4 (Rook can move from c4 to f4), how to get a mask for squares d4-e4 (excluding source and destination squares)?

I assume, once this is clear than vertical moves will be easy and diagonal moves can be calculated by using rotated bitboards.

**EDIT:**  the bitboard is represented with ulong/unsigned int64, with every pack of 8 bits representing a rank/row of the actual board.

Comment: If you are going for bitboards anyway, don't waste time generating them repeatedly. There are only 1953 ways to choose two cords on a chessboard. You can easily store those in an array.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Gave up on array's after trying to make a chess engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions here: The board is stored as a 64 bit number, each 8 byte block represents a row.  Each bit in the row represents a column (a..h).  You have start and end position as zero-based coordinates.  i.e: *`start = "C4" = [2,3]; end = "F4" = [5,3]`*

For horizontal moves with increasing columns, you can calculate the distance moved:  *`d = (F4-C4 = 3)`*.  Subtract 1 to exclude the destination, then the "trail" t of d-1 bits is *`t = (1<<(d-1))-1`*.  Shift the trail adjacent to the source piece to get the mask M: *`M = t<<(start.row*8 + start.column+1)`.*

This is equivalent to 
     `M = ((1<<d)-2)<<(start.row*8 + start.column)`

For horizontal moves the other way:

```
 d = (C4-F4 = -3)
 t = (1<<(-d-1))-1
 M = (t<<dest.column+1)
 //-or-
 M = ((1<<-d)-2)<<(dest.row*8 + dest.column)
```

For vertically increasing moves:

```
 d = (C7-C4 = 3)
 t=(1<<8)
 (d-1) times: { t |= (t<<8)}
 M = t << (start.row*8 + start.column)
```

For vertically decreasing moves:

```
 d = (C4-C7 = 3)
 t=(1<<8)
 (d-1) times: { t |= (t<<8)}
 M = t << (dest.row*8 + start.column)
```

For the vertical moves, you can replace the loop over d by storing the maximum "vertical trail"  `VT = 0x0101010101010101 = 72340172838076673`. Then mask out the right number of bits for the actual move.

This reduces the caclulation to `M = (VT & ((1<<(d*8)) - 2)) << (row*8+column)`.

You could probably do something similar for the diagonal moves.   Start with the max diagonal trail DT = `0x0102040810204080`, apply a mask to reduce it to `d` set bits, and shift to the start or end location, depending on which is closer to the edge.  This would need careful testing to make sure there were no edge cases which wrapped around into the wrong row.

*Edited to exclude both source and destination, and fix one-off errors*

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will try this out tonight and post the results.

Comment: One question: why do it this way ? Is this only for human player moves?  For AI moves, it would seem easier to calculate the non-blocked moves first, then pick the best one, rather than picking a move out of all the possible ones and then testing if it is blocked.

Comment: I'm doing it for validation of moves written in a game. In certain notations you have to figure out the source square of the piece that moved to a destination. For example, in some notation you might get just Rf4 for a move of rook from c4 to f4. And if you have more than 1 rook, you will have to use validation to find out which one can move to f4. Anyway, with some minor tweaks to your formulas, I got the right bitmasks for the squares in between 2 given. Will benchmark and post the results soon. Thank you!

Comment: in horizontal moves, you probably meant `M = (t<<dest.row* + dest.column)` that worked for me, just like you did for vertical moves

Answer (score 1):

Short of doing some up-front calculation and generating all possible masks for piece moves (a definite possibility), I'd expect that building up the masks at runtime would most likely be as expensive with respect to time as the simple 'lookup each square' approach.

Comment: that's why the question is if it possible to calculate the mask on the fly given two squares and let's say a direction (east/west)

Comment: It's definitely possible - but most likely no cheaper than the alternative, simpler, approach.

Comment: It is definitely cheaper to pre-compute all possibilities.

Comment: @sehe: No, I haven't profiled that myself, but it's the way everyone in the computer chess community does it.

Comment: I know for a fact that you're exaggerating. It's probably more than half-true, so I'll let it stand. I for me have found a way that seems to work better for me - although I must say that it involves modified chessboards (think 8x8x8) and still precomputes movetables. Just not in the form of bitboards

Answer (score 0):

Get the unity vector of direction (dx,dy)/dx

In this case, (1,0)

Then increment current position with that vector repeatedly until you reach destination. Underway increment/assign the corresponding matrix cells.

Comment: Seems like it would be no better than a bit-by-bit lookup from the EmptySquares bitboard.